Counting constrained permutations
Challenge:
Write a program or function that, given positive integers n, t, b, c, counts permutations of 1..n where:

Exactly t numbers are in their original position
Exactly b numbers are higher than their original position
Exactly c numbers are lower than their original position

Input:
Four non-negative integers n, t, b, c in any reasonable format.
Output:
The count of valid permutations satisfying all conditions.
Constraints:

t, b, c ≥ 0
t + b + c = n (you may assume inputs satisfy this)

Test cases:
n=3, t=1, b=1, c=1 → 3 
n=2, t=2, b=0, c=0 → 1  
n=3, t=0, b=2, c=1 → 1  
n=4, t=1, b=2, c=1 → 4

Example explanation for n=3, t=1, b=1, c=1:
The three valid permutations are:
[1,3,2]: 1 fixed, 3 higher, 2 lower
[2,1,3]: 3 fixed, 2 higher, 1 lower
[3,2,1]: 2 fixed, 1 lower, 3 higher

This is code-golf, so shortest solution in bytes wins!

For your example (n=3, t=1, b=1, c=1), isn't [3,2,1] also a valid permutation (2=fixed; 1=lower; 3=higher)? I'm also getting 4 instead of 6 for test case n=4, t=1, b=2, c=1.  Which two would I be missing after these four: [[1,3,4,2], [2,3,1,4], [2,4,3,1], [3,2,4,1]]?

@KevinCruijssen, test cases now fixed!

Is there a point in specifying an upper limit of n ≤ 500?

To elaborate on why @doubleunary is asking that: we have a consensus here that allows us to assume infinite time & memory.

@shaggy that, and I'd really like to see a computer that can generate the permutations of a 500-element list. The upper limit really calls for shortcut methods instead of iterative methods.

Removed the constraint! But yes it is possible for even n=1000, since this is a question I saw in a competition, but it likely involves dp and maybe combinatorics. I have yet to come up with a solution fast enough.

Maybe you want the restricted-complexity or restricted-time tags (but finding efficient algorithms isn't the focus of this site).

Yeah, I realize this might have been the wrong site for that. Any recommendations for more fitting places.

Do you have permission to repost the challenge here?

Yes it's allowed since the competition already ended.

math.stack, r/leetcode, r/codeforces… see Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

razimantv has outlined a recurrence.

Vyxal, 11 bytes
ɾṖƛż₍><Ṡ;$O

Try it Online!
         $O # Count the number of times [b, c] occurs in
ɾṖ          # Permutations of 1...n
  ƛ     ;   # For each
   ż        # Take the range from 1 to n
    ₍--     # Pair
     >      # Whether each is higher than its index
      <     # or lower
       Ṡ    # Sum these, giving [b, c]


Jelly,  13 11  10 bytes
-2 thanks to emanresu A (count occurrences instead of filtering and taking the length)
Œ!>ż<ɗR{§ċ

A dyadic Link that accepts n on the left and [b, c] on the right (t being implicit due to the \$t + b + c = n\$ guarantee).
Try it online! (see the permutations by removing the trailing L)
How?
Œ!>ż<ɗR{§ċ - Link: n; [b, c]
Œ!         - all permutations of {[1..n]}
      R{   - range of {n} -> [1..n]
     ɗ     - last three links as a dyad - f(Pemutations, [1..n]):
  >        -   {Pemutations} greater than {[1..n]} (vectorises)
    <      -   {Pemutations} less than {[1..n]} (vectorises)
   ż       -   zip these two lists of lists
        §  - sums -> [[#higher, #lower] for each Permutation]
         ċ - count occurrences of {[b, c]} in {that}


Potential faster approach
I believe this is correct but have not rigorously proved it to myself...
First calculate the number, \$P_{n,t}\$, of permutations of \$n\$ elements with exactly \$t\$ fixed points as
$$P_{n,t} = n! \sum_{i=t}^n \frac{-1^{(i-t)}}{t!(i-t)!}$$
Then calculate the number of derangements of the remaining \$n-t\$ elements (since they all need to move), \$D_{n-t}\$ as:
$$D_{n-t} = (n-t)! \sum_{i=0}^{n-t}\frac{-1^{(n-t-i)}}{(n-t-i)!}$$
(Or use the fact that \$D_{n-t}\$ is the nearest integer to \$\frac{(n-t)!}{e}\$, if you can get \$e\$ to arbitrary precision.)
Then calculate the number of derangements of \$(n-t)\$ with exactly \$b\$ exceedances (or equivalently \$c=t-n-b\$ exceedances as this is symmetric), \$D_{n-t,b}\$ using the recursive formula:
$$D_{s+1,x} = x D_{s,x} + (s+1-x) D_{s,x-1} + sD_{s-1,x-1}$$
(As per the OEIS entry A046739 - is there a closed form of this?)
Now the final count is given by:
$$\frac{P_{n,t}D_{n-t,b}}{D_{n-t}}$$
or, equivalently
$$\frac{P_{n,t}D_{n-t,c}}{D_{n-t}}$$
I'm not up to golfing that all in Jelly right now, although one way to golf the approach would be to use the fact that:
$$D_z = \sum_{i=0}^{z} D_{z,i}$$

11 based on my vyxal

Thanks, @emanresuA. I've improved to 10 by using the fact that < and > vectorise to realise I can zip the results, maybe you can use that approach in Vyxal.

Nekomata + -n, 8 bytes
↕x-±→Ħ-ž

Attempt This Online!
Take input as n [b,t,c].
↕x-±→Ħ-ž
↕           Find a permutation of [0,1,...,n-1]
 x          Push [0,1,...,n-1]
  -         Subtract
   ±        Signum
    →       Increment
     Ħ      Histogram; count occurrences of 0,1,2,...
      -     Subtract [b,t,c]
       ž    Check if all elements are 0

-n counts the number of solutions.

Japt -x, 22 20 14 bytes
Takes the targets as an array in the order c,t,b.
o á ËüÈgYÃmÊeV

Try it
o á ËüÈgYÃmÊeV     :Implicit input of integer U=n and array V=[c,t,b]
o                  :Range [0,U)
  á                :Permutations
    Ë              :Map
     ü             :  Group & sort by
      È            :  The following function
       g           :    Sign of difference with
        Y          :      0-based index
         Ã         :  End grouping
          m        :  Map
           Ê       :    Length
            eV     :  Is equal to V?
                   :Implicit output of sum of resulting array

Original 20 bytes
Preserving this one as I quite liked the construction of the array of comparison operators. Takes t, b & c as an array in reverse order.
o á £VË¶XèEg§¬o³i>Ã×

Try it
o á £VË¶XèEg§¬o³i>Ã×     :Implicit input of integer U=n and array V=[c,b,t]
o                        :Range [0,U)
  á                      :Permutation
    £                    :Map each X
     VË                  :  Map each D in V
       ¶                 :    Is D equal to
        Xè               :      Count the elements in X that return true when compared to their 0-based indices thusly
          Eg             :        Index E into
            §            :          "<="
             ¬           :          Split
              o          :          Modify the last element
               ³         :            Triplicate (to give the strictly-equal-to comparison operator. Duplicating would also work, to give the loosely-equal-to operator.)
                i>       :          Prepend ">"
                  Ã      :  End inner map
                   ×     :  Reduce by multplication
                         :Implicit output of sum of resulting array


Is this generating all permutations? The question explicitly specifies an upper limit of n ≤ 500, which I think means about 1.2e+1134 permutations.

@doubleunary, yes under our consensus of being able to assume infinite time & memory.

OK, so perhaps there's no point in specifying an upper limit in the question in the first place.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 97 bytes
Tr[1^Select[b={##2};s=Range@#;#-s&/@Permutations@s,(f=#;Count[f,u_/;Sign@u==#]&/@{0,1,-1}==b)&]]&

Try it online!

05AB1E, 12 bytes
Lœʒā.S1Ý¢Q}g

Inputs as \$n\$ and \$[t,b]\$ (without \$c\$, since \$t+b+c=n\$ is guaranteed).
Try it online or verify all test cases.
If we would take all four values as inputs, it's 1 byte longer by replacing 1Ý ([0,1]) with ®1Ÿ ([-1,0,1]) and taking the second input in the order \$[c,t,b]\$:
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
L          # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input-integer n]
 œ         # Get all permutations of this list
  ʒ        # Filter this list of permutation-lists by:
   ā       #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
    .S     #  Vectorized compare each value at the same positions:
           #   -1 if a<b; 0 if a==b; 1 if a>b
      1Ý   #  Push pair [0,1]
        ¢  #  Count how many times those occur in the list of compares
         Q #  Check whether this list equals the second (implicit) input-pair
  }g       # After the filter: pop and push the length
           # (which is output implicitly as result)


Uiua, 24 bytes
/+≡(/↧⬚0=°⊚+1±-°⊏)⧅≠⟜⇡⊙¤

Try it!
/+≡(/↧⬚0=°⊚+1±-°⊏)⧅≠⟜⇡⊙¤
                   ⧅≠⟜⇡     # generate all permutations of 0..n-1
  ≡(              )          # for each row:
              ±-°⊏          #     get the sign of the comparison to the original indices
         °⊚+1               #     find the counts of [>, =, <]
    /↧⬚0=               ⊙¤  #     do they match [b, t, c] (filling empty spaces with 0)?
/+                          # count those which are true


JavaScript (ES7), 94 bytes
-1 thanks to @l4m2
Expects (n)(b,c) (t is ignored). Simple brute-force search.
n=>g=(b,c,k=0,m=2**n-1)=>m?(h=j=>m>>j&&h(-~j)+(m>>j&1&&g(b-(j<k),c-(j>k),k+1,m^1<<j)))``:!b&!c

Try it online!

Do reading bc than tb save a byte by == => >?

Python 3, 154 147 137 bytes
lambda n,t,b,c,R=range:sum(sorted((r[a]>a)-(r[a]<a)for a in R(n))==[-1]*c+[0]*t+b*[1]for r in I.permutations(R(n)))
import itertools as I

Try it online!

You've created a variable R=range since you do this twice, but forgot to use it at the end (the I.permutations(range(n)) can be I.permutations(R(n)) for -4 bytes), and you also have an unused ,q=0 you can remove for another -4 bytes. :) Also, you can put the f= in the header by putting the import below the lambda for another -2 bytes. And since the challenge guarantees $n=t+b+c$, you can also change the check from ==[-1]*c+[0]*t+b*[1] to [c:]==[0]*t+b*[1] for another -3 bytes. In total: try it online - 138 bytes

Charcoal, 61 bytes
⊞υ⊞ＯＥ³Ｎ…·¹ＮＦυ«≔⊟ιηＦη«≔⊕⁻›κＬη‹κＬηζ¿§ιζ⊞υ⊞ＯＥι⁻λ⁼μζ⁻η⟦κ⟧»Ｍ¬η→»Ｉⅈ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order c t b n. Explanation:
⊞υ⊞ＯＥ³Ｎ…·¹ＮＦυ«

Start a breadth-first search with an array c t b and a range from 1 to n.
≔⊟ιηＦη«

Loop over the remaining elements in the range.
≔⊕⁻›κＬη‹κＬηζ

See whether this element would be fixed, higher or lower when placed at the next last position.
¿§ιζ

If there is an available place for an element of that type, then...
⊞υ⊞ＯＥι⁻λ⁼μζ⁻η⟦κ⟧

... decrement the number of places and remove that element from the range, and push the result to the search list.
»Ｍ¬η→

Keep count of completely valid permutations.
»Ｉⅈ

Output the final count.

JavaScript (Node.js), 90 bytes
f=(n,g,l,F=2**n-1,G,b=F&-F)=>b?f(n,g,l,F^=b,G^b)+f(--n,g-(2**n>b),l-(2**n<b),F^G):!(n|g|l)

Try it online!
n: input (length)
g: input (greater)
l: input (less)
F: flags (available bits)
G: flags (bits not used here because using here considered in somewhere else)
b: pick a bit from F

